# Python-Wikipedia Automated Downloader

Tags: python, download, python-3.x, wikipedia, pywikibot

[Using Python 3.1] Does anyone have any idea how to make a Python 3 application allow the user to write a text file with multiple words separated with commas. The program should read the file, and download the Wikipedia page of the requested item. e.g. if they typed hello,python-3,chicken it would go to Wikipedia and download http://www.wikipedia.com/wiki/hello, http://www.wikip...  Anyone think they can do this?

When I say "download" I mean download the text, doesn't matter about images.

Comment: This sounds like homework to me. If you expect to get some help, put some effort and show us some code.

Comment: I have an idea of how to make it, yeah.  Show me yours and I'll show you mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/urllib.request.html).

Answer (score 1):

You described exactly how to make such a program. So what is the question?

You read the file, split on commas, and download the URL. Done!

Comment: i know how to do the extra stuff, reading text files... but i dont know how to do the downloading of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code, it downloads the html, without the images, but you can access them from the xml file that is being parsed to get the url.

```
from time import sleep
import urllib
import urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom, Node

def main():
    print "Hello World"

    keywords = []

    key_file = open("example.txt", 'r')
    if key_file:
        temp_lines = key_file.readlines()

        for keyword_line in temp_lines:
            keywords.append(keyword_line.rstrip("\n"))

        key_file.close()

    print "Total keywords: %d" % len(keywords)
    for keyword in keywords:
        url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=xml&action=opensearch&search=" + keyword
        xmldoc = minidom.parse(urllib.urlopen(url))
        root_node = xmldoc.childNodes[0]

        section_node = None
        for node in root_node.childNodes:
            if node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE and \
            node.nodeName == "Section":
                section_node = node
                break

        if section_node is not None:
            items = []
            for node in section_node.childNodes:
                if node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE and \
                node.nodeName == "Item":
                    items.append(node)

            if len(items) == 0:
                print "NO results found"
            else:
                print "\nResults found for " + keyword + ":\n"
                for item in items:
                    for node in item.childNodes:
                        if node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE and \
                        node.nodeName == "Text":
                            if len(node.childNodes) == 1:
                                print node.childNodes[0].data.encode('utf-8')

                file_name = None
                for node in items[0].childNodes:
                    if node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE and \
                    node.nodeName == "Text":
                        if len(node.childNodes) == 1:
                            file_name = "Html\%s.html" % node.childNodes[0].data.encode('utf-8')
                            break

                if file_name is not None:
                    file = open(file_name, 'w')
                    if file:
                        for node in items[0].childNodes:
                            if node.nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE and \
                            node.nodeName == "Url":
                                if len(node.childNodes) == 1:
                                    user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0b; Windows NT 6.0)'
                                    header = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
                                    request = urllib2.Request(url=node.childNodes[0].data, headers=header)
                                    file.write(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
                                    file.close()
                                    break


    print "Sleeping"
    sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You should not answer a homework question with code, especially when the asker shows little amount of code and lots of "ideas"